# Is Decorator Pattern respected?

Tags: java, design-patterns

As described in many examples (for example http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern#Java) abstract Decorator class only has to forward component methods.

But In my case I need to override a method just in the abstract class (for type convertion):

**Component**

```
public interface PagerRepository<T> {
    List<T> getPageEntries();
}
```

**Concrete component**

```
public abstract class ConcretePagerRepository<T> implements PagerRepository<T> {

    // @Override ...

}
```

**Abstract Decorator**

```
public abstract class PagerRepositoryConvertionDecorator<T, S>
    implements PagerRepository<S> {

    protected PagerRepository<T> repo;

    public PagerRepositoryConvertionDecorator(PagerRepository<T> repo) {
        this.repo = repo;
    }

    @Override
    public List<S> getPageEntries() {
        List<T> entities = this.repo.getPageEntries();
        List<S> dtos = new ArrayList<S>();
        for (T e : entities) {
            dtos.add(convert(e));
        }
        return dtos;
    }

    protected abstract S convert(T entity);
}
```

Is this a correct decorator pattern implementation?

Comment: If you can live without decorator, do so.

Comment: ahah, yes I'm sure... It's just curiosity... :)

Comment: Isn't that `ENTITY` supposed to be simply `T`?

Comment: @Riccardo you're right.

Comment: May it's an adapter - in coverts interfaces - from PagerRepository<T> to PagerRepository<S>? It doesn't add/hide methods so seems like a decorator.

Comment: Isn't convert a template method here. I see Template Method Pattern!!

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks like you want to simply reuse an abstract method implementation and apply some conversion afterwards - if using third party code, I would approve this approach, but in this case you are in control of the class hierarchy and so I would extract common behavior in an abstract base class your `ConcretePagerRepository` and `PagerRepositoryConvertionDecorator` each will be extending. Besides, overwriting an already overwritten abstract method is not particularly good coding style, because you are secretly inheriting code. Methods designed for inheritance should be abstract or empty, or, if not intended to be inherited, `final`.